# How do I force dreamweaver to encode PHP files properly?

Tags: php, encoding, dreamweaver, emoji

Often times when I re-open a php document that has emoji characters inside of it, they turn into non-emoji codes. I've set preferences for new document creation to be UTF-8, and for it to apply to opening existing documents - but it hasn't helped. Anyone have a suggestion?

[image: Dreamweaver Preferences]

[image: Unencoded emoji]

Comment: Did you also post to the dreamweaver user forum? (usually the first place to check when it comes to "how do I use Adobe software" before hitting up places like superuser or stackoverflow)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes - though I posted here initially as I found some similar questions from my google search. Adobe forums are not a place I hang around as much as SO/SE sites.